# ThreeJs + OrbitControls - How to adjust the mouse pan speed?

Tags: three.js

In the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls) of `OrbitControls` there are various properties to adjust the speed of zoom and so on; e.g., `zoomSpeed`, `rotateSpeed`

Unfortunately I couldn't find a property to adjust the speed of the panning, when using a mouse. I only found `keyPanSpeed`, but it doesn't affect the speed of panning via a mouse.

Is there no such property? How can I slow down the panning speed when using a mouse?

Comment: How is it that panning is too fast in your use case? Can you reproduce the issue be editing  this dev-branch [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptgwhemb/)?

Comment: @WestLangley https://jsfiddle.net/5rc30qsb/ As you can see, zoom and rotation is now quite slow while using a mouse, but panning is still at default speed while using a mouse.

Comment: I see... You reduced the zoom and rotation speeds significantly, and you want the pan speed to be reduced, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can consider adding pan speed as a feature of `OrbitControls`.

In the mean time, you can hack in the change like so:

Add this:

```
this.panSpeed = 1.0;
```

Modify TWO occurrences of this:

```
//panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart );
panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart ).multiplyScalar( scope.panSpeed );
```

three.js r.90